# "suggestions on" or "suggestions at"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Example usage:

> I've changed the post a lot by following suggestions on the original question.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither on or at work really. I would say something like:

> I've edited the post a lot after following suggestions to change the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer

> I've changed the post a lot by following suggestions about the original question.

Comment: cool idea, I did not think about using the word about.